# How to use resource attribute on I18n Devise flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use a resource attribute in one of my internationalized strings used by Devise. I've created a new `SessionsController` which inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` and in it, I've override the `create` method, like:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

I'm redirecting to an specific path and passing the `resource`. I can debug using byebug and I see the resource from the logged user with its attributes, but still I don't know how to pass such attributes in order to be used within a "locale" message, like:

```
devise:
  sessions:
    user:
      signed_in: 'You have signed in successfully. Welcome %{name}!'
```

Currently `name` doesn't print the value from the user's name, so, I'm wonder how to achieve it.

I'm displaying the messages in a `_message.html.erb` partial, like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-icon alert-dismissible alert-<%= key %> flash-alert" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My routes include the SessionsController:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }, skip: [:registrations]
  as :user do
    ...
    post 'login', to: 'sessions#create', as: :user_session
  end
end
```

And also the POST 'login' is pointing to the DeviseSessions#create action and controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `name` in the `options` params for the `set_flash_message!`.

`set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in, { name: resource.name })`

Comment: I did it work creating a `flash[:notice]` also using the `signed_in` and passing the resource attribute as the value, but it seems to be the best way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also did it work just creating a `flash[:notice]` message in the `create` method:

```
def create
  ...
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t('devise.sessions.user.signed_in', name: resource.name)
  ...
end
```

But @André's answer works also perfectly.